# Working with Pythomnic3k and OpenSLL

Tags: python, openssl, smpp, pythomnic3k

I need to make a client side script that can send messages via the SMPP protocol. So, far I've started out with Pythomnic3k. In a part of the set up, you need to install the following:

```
   * Python 3 with threads and OpenSSL support. It is seldom installed
     by default in any of today OSes. Use your package manager to install or
     download it and build manually with the above OpenSSL and thread support.
     http://www.python.org/
```

Right now, I am note sure what to make of this. Do I need to download `pyOpenSSL` or do I need to download a special version of Python 3. Also, my current version installed is 3.3.2, will that be compatible with the PyOpenSSL library that is using [version 3.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.13.1) for windows?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can start with any vanilla Python 3 package for your OS you can find. Try it and see if it works.

pyOpenSSL or any other 3rd party SSL module is not required. OpenSSL support (through Python 3 builtin _ssl module using system openssl libs) is optional for some parts of Pythomnic3k and there is a good chance your Python is compiled with it already.